# Choosing the right number of tokens in a dictionary for an LDA topic modelling analysis

Tags: topic-model, lda, spacy, dictionary

I have a data set of customers with n complaints.
As a result, I want to perform topic modelling to find topics that customers talk about in their complaints. For this I use LDA from spacy.

I have created a dictionary and a corpus. My data set has 10000 documents and these consist of a total of 25000 tokens. When creating the dictionary, you can use a "keep_n" parameter to control how many of the most frequently occurring tokens should be in the dictionary. Are there best practices for the keep_n parameter?

The larger the parameter, the larger the model is likely to be, so it probably makes sense to find a trade-off.